# Why i am getting connection error when i change the parameter in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I like to join 3 tables to get data as:
required fields from table1
and record_count from table2
and sum(amount) from table3

I am using the following query:

```
select a.cde,a.name,count(b.TransID) as t_cnt, 
       sum(c.Amt) as c_sumofamt 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b 
    on a.cde=b.cde 
inner join table3 c 
    on a.cde=c.cde 
where a.Bcde='TVM' GROUP BY a.cde;
```

Note: Its working fine if (where `a.Bcde='TVM'`) but not with anyother branch_code "`Bcde`"

TVM is having few records (just 40 records)

But if i give (`where a.Bcde='CBE'`) its not working - taking long time and giving conn. err.

For your information its haivng more records:

```
6000+ records in table1
50000+ records in table2
100000+ records in table3
```

How to handle this situation?
Expecting your valuable reply.

regards,
Sensa.

Comment: You are doing a sum on 100k records, maybe this could be slow. Can you just perform a `SELECT sum(Amt) FROM table where Bcde='CBE'` ?

Comment: yes.  Like:   select a.cde,a.name,count(b.TransID) as t_cnt, 
       sum(c.Amt) as c_sumofamt 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b 
    on a.cde=b.cde 
inner join table3 c 
    on a.cde=c.cde 
where a.Bcde='CBE' GROUP BY a.cde;

Comment: Try to execute the line i gave you and see if the server respond with an acceptable time.

Comment: Bcde field is not available in table3. Its available in table1 and table2. For all the 3 tables i am using the field "cde" to link.

I can able to execute your expected query using the following query:  SELECT a.cbe,sum(Amt) FROM table1 a inner join table3 c on a.cde=c.cde where a.Bcde='CBE' group by a.cde;

Comment: If i use limit then its working fine but took 33 secs time.

[example: SELECT a.cbe,sum(Amt) FROM table1 a inner join table3 c on a.cde=c.cde where a.Bcde='CBE' group by a.cde LIMIT 500;]

Comment: What are your indexes in these tables ?

Comment: This summary query isn't quite correct.  Try `GROUP BY a.cde, a.name`. Also it may help if you use `EXPLAIN`.  This is a complex query that can benefit from several indexes. It's hard to help you any further unless you mention what indexes are available and whether you're using myISAM or InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

First i like to Thank all for spending your valuable time here in this post.

I got the solution by the help of people from another forum.

Solution is:

```
select a.cde,a.name,count(b.TransID) as t_cnt, 
       sum(c.Amt) as c_sumofamt 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b 
    on a.cde=b.cde 
inner join table3 c 
    on
```

> b.cde=c.cde

```
where a.Bcde='TVM' GROUP BY a.cde;
```

**Note** the second inner join. they suggest me to join from second table to third table - and its working fine now.

But i don't know what is the difference if i use: a.cbe=c.cde instead of b.cde=c.cde ?

If anyone knows please share with me.

Expecting your valuable reply in this regard.